# Can a distributed polling model be applied to a mobile MailClient applicaton?

Tags: networking, email, configuration, email-server, gmail

I am trying to figure out server architecture to run an app that is similar to a MailClient app on a mobile device. Basically, the app will need to check a persons email (gmail api, pop, or imap) in the background, then initiate a push notification on their phone. I have identified two possible architectures for this app:

- Distributed: The email address is polled and checked on the mobile device in the background. The means everything basically runs on the persons mobile device and not on a central server.
- Centralized: The email address is polled from a main centralized server and the server sends the push notification to the mobile device.

My thinking is that centralized server polling would be a major problem. If the app becomes popular we would have to build necessary server infrastructure to handle the load. Additionally, if we had thousands of downloads of the app, then the server would be checking thousands of emails from 1 IP address. What are the chances that this 1 IP address could be blacklisted by a major email provider?

I guess it would all come down to what kind of sandboxing Android and iOS has for the apps. We are currently using react native as the mobile framework. Does anyone know if the sandboxing would prevent the ability to check emails in the background via the gmail api, pop or imap methods?

Answer (score 0):

As framed, there are strong arguments against both.

1. Against distributed- polling from mobile devices over mobile networks particularly with old protocols like IMAP and POP is extremely wasteful. Doubly wasteful if any processing is occurring on some or all of the polled emails. The cost of polling is the reason notification protocols were created in the first place. Finally, if you have to iterate on your offering, mobile apps are the worst way to do that.
2. Against centralized- collecting people's email credentials is privacy invading, an obstacle to scale, and makes you a target. Email, for all its faults, is an important custodial protocol.

Assuming that the offering here is something that identifies and processes specific emails with some special sauce and then notifies users when certain events occur, consider instead offering users an email address on a new domain which by default forwards to theirs. Users provide your @wayofthefuture.com email in whatever places are compatible with your offering. Then deploy your polling and processing using a centralized architecture. Scaling this kind of processing is trivial and inexpensive to do with cloud services like Amazon. This model also avoids custodial and reputational risks.

Feel free to edit the question if this misses something fundamental.

Comment: I've been reading that Android offers something called SyncAdapter which will allow IMAP polling with light battery usage. I'm not sure if iOS has something similar. I think that would help with the battery problem. The major problem though: what if we have 1000 email addresses with the same imap server. Would centralized architecture cause possible blacklisting of our server IP?

Comment: If you are operating a central architecture at scale and engaging in activities that could be considered abusive of some downstream provider's service, be proactive about communicating with them, explaining what you are doing, and ask for help. Assuming you are operating in accordance with their terms of service and so forth and you are helping their customers, they should help you. Perhaps they allocate special gateways with optimized access, or open up a more efficient protocol. The central approach opens up collaboration opportunities that distributed does not.